# In EJB how @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) will commit my jdbc transaction as well?

Tags: transactions, ejb, transactional, distributed-transactions

In EJB I have found that there is an annotation available like @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) , So transaction will be managed by container itself. But with use of it, you don't need to write con.commit() as Container will take care of it(Which I am just guessing as I am new in EJB). So my confusion is that how jdbc transaction gets associated with container Transaction that it get committed at the end of method having annotation @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, unless an exception occurs in which case the transaction will be rolled back.
This is a example of a **Container Managed Transaction**.
The other option is **User Managed Transaction**, where the boundaries of the transactions are defined with tx.begin(), tx.commit() etc.
For most needs Container Managed transactions are enough.